# Incorrect certificate installation

Tags: openssl, certificate, tomcat7, centos5

We are working in a CentOS which have the following characteristic:

Operating system    CentOS Linux 5.5
Webmin version  1.510
Kernel and CPU  Linux 2.6.18-194.3.1.el5xen on i686
Processor information   Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.20GHz, 1 cores

Over this OS we have tomcat 7 running for several domains in the path:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/software/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/software/tomcat7
```

there we have some applications runing.

The key was generated as a PKCS#12 file and converted to a Java KeyStore with keytool:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass keystorepass -destkeypass addkeypass -destkeystore myKeyStore.jks -srckeystore serverabcdj0.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass PKCS12pass -alias latiendamiga.com
```

CSR generation:

```
keytool -certreq -alias latiendamiga.com -file csraj0s.txt -keystore myKeyStore.jks
```

Then I have installed the SSL certificate which I have acquired from CA GoDaddy. This installation was made in a wrong way by misunderstanding, I have installed as root a wrong certificate,  then I have deleted the certificates (root, intermediate & Primary) and after that I have installed the correct ones, when I list my keystore I can see:

```
    ***CMD***:-list -keystore myKeyStore.jks

    ***ASW***:Keystore type: JKS
    Keystore provider: SUN

    Your keystore contains 3 entries

    root, Aug 21, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XXXXXXX
    tomcat, Aug 21, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XXXXXXX
    intermed, Aug 21, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XXXXXXX
```

But when I try to check if certificates work properly I'm getting errors which I don't understand.

I have test certificate installation as follow (command CMD / answer ASW):

```
    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -state -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW[/u][/b]: CONNECTED(00000003)
    SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
    SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
    4721:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -nbio_test -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW[/u][/b]: CONNECTED(00000003)
    write W BLOCK
    write W BLOCK
    write W BLOCK
    write W BLOCK
    write W BLOCK
    write W BLOCK
    4728:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -msg -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW***: CONNECTED(00000003)
    >>> SSL 2.0 [length 0077], CLIENT-HELLO
        01 03 01 00 4e 00 00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00 38 00
        00 35 00 00 16 00 00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0 00 00
        33 00 00 32 00 00 2f 03 00 80 00 00 05 00 00 04
        01 00 80 00 00 15 00 00 12 00 00 09 06 00 40 00
        00 14 00 00 11 00 00 08 00 00 06 04 00 80 00 00
        03 02 00 80 00 00 ff 93 fc 24 f4 45 d0 ec bf 2d
        3d 4d ae 59 e8 77 1d 6c 04 5f 59 0d 5b 19 a2 c3
        78 74 06 fc ab 4a 72
    4732:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -debug -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW***: CONNECTED(00000003)
    write to 0x90372f8 [0x90b5528] (121 bytes => 121 (0x79))
    0000 - 80 77 01 03 01 00 4e 00-00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00   .w....N... ..9..
    0010 - 38 00 00 35 00 00 16 00-00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0   8..5............
    0020 - 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00-2f 03 00 80 00 00 05 00   ..3..2../.......
    0030 - 00 04 01 00 80 00 00 15-00 00 12 00 00 09 06 00   ................
    0040 - 40 00 00 14 00 00 11 00-00 08 00 00 06 04 00 80   @...............
    0050 - 00 00 03 02 00 80 00 00-ff 97 5c 69 fd 61 9d 2e   ..........\i.a..
    0060 - e5 58 60 d5 83 9b 1a 70-ce 3c b2 0e b3 3b 03 31   .X`....p.<...;.1
    0070 - 0d 02 16 09 1f 76 eb d2-7f                        .....v...
    read from 0x90372f8 [0x90baa88] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
    4737:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -showcerts -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW***: CONNECTED(00000003)
    4742:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -key myKeyStore.jks -state -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW***: unable to load client certificate private key file
    4762:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
    -bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe

    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -verify depth -state -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW[/u][/b]: verify depth is 0
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
    SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
    4770:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:

    ***CMD***: echo "" | openssl s_client -nbio -state -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443

    ***ASW***: CONNECTED(00000003)
    turning on non blocking io
    SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
    SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
    SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
    write R BLOCK
    4774:error:140780E5:SSL routines:SSL23_READ:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:142:

    ***CMD***: openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443 -prexit

    ***ASW***: CONNECTED(00000003)
    4810:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:536:
    ---
    no peer certificate available
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
    ---
    New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
    Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : SSLv3
        Cipher    : 0000
        Session-ID:
        Session-ID-ctx:
        Master-Key:
        Key-Arg   : None
        Krb5 Principal: None
        Start Time: 1440220364
        Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
        Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    ---
```

Regarding environment configuration it are as follow:

/usr/local/software/tomcat7/conf/server.xml

```
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" />

    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25" port="443" keystoreFile="/etc/webmin/myKeyStore.jks" keystorePass="mypass" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

/usr/local/software/tomcat7/conf/web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Automatic SSL Forward</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>
                CONFIDENTIAL
            </transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

I need some help to understand what is wrong and what I must to do to fix it.

Please, could somebody tell me if there are any documentation where I can search for a solution or how I could check what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keystore contains 3 trustedCertEntries, but no private key. This cannot work. Add to your question how you have created the key and CSR for GoDaddy.

Comment: thanks for fast answer, there is rquested data

Comment: key genration:

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass keystorepass -destkeypass addkeypass -destkeystore myKeyStore.jks -srckeystore serverabcdj0.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass PKCS12pass -alias latiendamiga.com

CSR generation:

keytool -certreq -alias latiendamiga.com -file csraj0s.txt -keystore myKeyStore.jks

Comment: I saw your edit attempt. It would have been better to delete myKeyStore.jks before starting again. But this is not a problem. It would still be better to delete the SSL certificate with alias 'tomcat' from the keystore, so it is not 2x in the keystore. Then check that the key entry contains now the right certificate with 'keytool -v -list ...'.

Comment: It doesn't work, probably because cartificates are not correct, I have sent a mail to CA to clarify what certificates I must to use exactly.

I have deleted all certificates and when I try to add again it shows that alias already exist.
Do you know how fixt last point?

Comment: I'm checking in deep I have two jsk and key files, Also keytool -v -list and keytool -list keystore are showing odd information, I'll revert back as soon as I understand better the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the private key that belongs to the SSL certificate is not in the keystore (anymore). It contains only three trusted certificate entries, but no key pair entry.

So you will have to repeat the conversion step from PKCS#12 to Java KeyStore (`keytool -importkeystore ...`). After this step you have the key in `myKeyStore.jks` again under the alias 'latiendamiga.com'. You should verify this with `keytool -list ...`.

Then import the certificates from GoDaddy again. First root and intermediate CA as trusted certificates:

```
keytool -importcert -alias root -file <root ca file>
keytool -importcert -alias intermed -file <intermediate ca file>
```

Then the SSL certificate:

```
keytool -importcert -alias latiendamiga.com -trustcacerts -file <ssl cert file>
```

Comment: I have deleted all certificated and private key and added it again but it doesn't work.executing list -v and three certificates and private key are showed but if I try https://www.latiendamiga.com application is not displayed.
I have executed echo "" | openssl s_client -nbio -state -showcerts -connect www.latiendamiga.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
turning on non blocking io
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
write R BLOCK

Comment: Ok, so there is obviously a second problem. Are you testing with openssl 0.98 from the CentOS 5.5 machine (which is really old)? There might be a compatibility problem between openssl and tomcat (s. for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164102/how-to-globally-configure-secure-clients-using-openssl-on-oracle-linux-5-rhel-5). Especially because you set `sslProtocol="TLS"`. Did you try to connect with a browser, KeyStore Explorer or a recent openssl version?

Comment: I am not sure to get your quetion "Did you try to connect with a browser, KeyStore Explorer or a recent openssl version?"  I'm triying to update my CentOS version but what do you mean with "connect with a browser, KeyStore Explorer" at this moment I'm using Mozilla Firefox 39.0, Internet Explorer 11.0 and Google Chrome 44.0.2403.157 m. Txs again.

Comment: @fern It seems like you always used openssl to check if SSL is working. Do you get an error in Firefox or IE as well when you open www.latiendamiga.com?

Comment: @Oikron if we try to  open page, whith https://..., it fails from IE, firefox or chrome. We are upgrading CentOS from 5.5 to 6.x to get TSLv2 capability. I hope it fix, we must to start app asap.. Txs for your comments.